# Type Error: Cannot Read property 'forEach' of underfined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Cannot Read property 'forEach' of underfined is the error i get when i try runing my bot and im not sure how to fix it... i have already tried  looking but no luck and im a quite new to discod.js and java script so any help at all would be apreciated!

**code**

```
const { config } = require('dotenv');

const client = new Client({
    disableEveryone: true
});

client.commands = new Collection();
client.aliases = new Collection();

config({
    path: __dirname + "/.env"
})

["command"].forEach(handler => {

});(handler => {
    require(`./handler/${handler}`)(client);
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Hi, ${client.user.username} is now online!`);

    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",
        game: {
            name: "me getting developed",
            type: "WATCHING"
        }  
    });
});

client.on("message", async message => {
    const prefix = "_";

    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    if (!message.member) message.member = await message.guild.fetchMember(message);

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (cmd.length === 0) return;

    let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
    if (!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));

    if (command)
        command.run(client, message, args);
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: Is it a typo on `["command"].forEach(handler => {})( handler =>` ? Your code has an empty forEach.

Comment: No, Sadly not... It did fix another issue but sadly not the one i was looking for

Comment: Please provide more details. What was the other error ? Are you sure the error is in the code your shared ? You only have on forEach and it is perfectly valid

Comment: Yes it is in the code i provided, I use VSC and it showed it on the terminal the exact thing was...  the error is ["command"].forEach(handler
                                                           -----------------------------------------
Type Error: Cannot Read Property "forEach" of underfined